# having problem with a query

Tags: mysql

I have a DB with `user_id` and `last_updated`

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_updated) as timestamp 
  FROM online 
 WHERE user_id > 0 
 GROUP_BY user_id
```

I'm getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'GROUP_BY
>   user_id' at line 1

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_updated) as timestamp 
  FROM online 
 WHERE user_id > 0 
 GROUP_BY user_id
```

Someone suggested I use the above query so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

I googled `group_by` and don't see what I did wrong. I thought maybe the `as timestamp` but not sure!

Comment: It's [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), not GROUP_BY.

Comment: Lol i cant belive that now that i look back at my search it just like you said thats just to funny i did not see that!

Comment: once again thanks i cant believe it was something so simple that i over looked!

Comment: tomalak thanks for making my question look like it was suppose to

Answer (score 5):

It's `GROUP BY` not `GROUP_BY`...

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_updated) as timestamp 
  FROM online 
 WHERE user_id > 0 
 GROUP BY user_id
```

#### UPDATE

Per comments, also note that *timestamp* is a reserved word. You should chance the alias (i.e. `max_last_updated`) or escape it with backticks (i.e. `timestamp`)

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_updated) as timestamp 
FROM online WHERE user_id > 0 GROUP_BY user_id
```

to

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_updated) as `timestamp` 
FROM online WHERE user_id > 0 GROUP BY user_id
```

Reserved words *(such as `timestamp`)* can only be used a identifiers if enclosed by backticks '`'.

Also `GROUP_BY` -> `GROUP BY` *(Two words, SQL keywords never have a '_' in them)*.

Even better is to not use reserved words as they are confusing *(and backticks make my head hurt)*

Comment: lol the answer is in the comment in my question! that's what i get for not paying attn to the syntax

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a data type used by MySQL, try to change it to some thing else.

Comment: Or delimit your field names like you should be doing anyway.